# ¿Cómo actualizar datos de un usuario sin que se modifique la password en django rest framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, djangorestframework

Tengo un inconveniente con una 'api' que estoy creando.
Tengo el siguiente modelo de  **Personas**:

```
class Personas(User):
#Definicion de datos
ADMINISTRADOR = 'AD'
PROFESIONAL = 'PR'
USUARIO = 'US'

#DEFINICION DE ENUM TYPE
ACCESO_PERSONA = [
    (ADMINISTRADOR,'ADIMINISTRADOR'),
    (PROFESIONAL,'PROFESIONAL'),
    (USUARIO,'USUARIO'),
]


"""Model definition for Personas."""
idPersona = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
Nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False, null = False)
Apaterno = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False, null = False)
Amaterno = models.CharField(max_length = 60, blank = False, null = False)
fNacimiento = models.DateField(auto_now = False, blank = False, null = False)
idFacebook = models.CharField(max_length = 15, blank = True, null = True)
srcFoto = models.ImageField(upload_to = path_and_rename('imgs/perfiles/') , height_field = None , width_field = None , max_length = 250, blank = False, null = False)
idCiudad = models.ForeignKey('Ciudades', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
Acceso = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = ACCESO_PERSONA)
```

Como lo pueden notar este modelo hereda los atributos del modelo **User** propio de **django**, por tanto también dentro de sus atributos tiene los campos **email** y **password**. Cuando hago un **post** para guardar en este modelo, todo funciona de maravilla, sin embargo cuando hago un **put** o un **patch** actualizando cualquier campo del modelo se modifica el campo **password**; generando un problema al momento de la autenticación pues la contraseña se pierde.

La vista que uso para hacer la inserción es la siguiente:

```
class PersonasViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Personas.objects.all()
serializer_class = PersonasSerializer
```

El serializador que tengo es el siguiente:

```
class PersonasSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Personas
    fields = ('idPersona','Nombre','Apaterno', 'Amaterno','email', 'password', 'fNacimiento', 'idFacebook', 'srcFoto', 'idCiudad','Acceso')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
    read_only_fields = ['srcFoto']


def create(self, validated_data):

    validated_data['username']= validated_data['email']
    validated_data['is_active']= False
    user = super(PersonasSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()
    Token.objects.create(user=user)


    return user
```

¿Cómo se pueden dar cuenta de que sobrescribo el método create para poder encriptar la contraseña? El error ocurre cuando hago un put o un patch, y según lo que veo es porque primero no se pasa una nueva contraseña puesto que el campo password queda vacío y al sobrescribirlo la contraseña cambia de valor; y lo segundo porque en teoría solo necesito sobreescribir el campo password cuando el usuario modifique la contraseña. Entonces lo que le pido a uds son ideas de como puedo hacer que esta parte solo modifique el campo password, solo si la contraseña actual se modifica.

Comment: lo ideal es que crees otro serializer que no envie la clave

Comment: @JackNavaRow, hice una prueba similar; sin embargo, pasa lo mismo. luego de hacer alguna actualización; ya sea mi nombre o fecha de nacimiento, al momento de loguearme ya no me deja con las supuestas credenciales que tengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te quiero dar una alternativa mas facil y menos complicada. Ademas de que considero de mala practica lo que estas intentando hacer.

En ves de crear el modelo `Persona` y heredar de `User`, creo que es mejor extender el modelo de `User` con `AbstractUser`.

De la siguiente manera:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # Aqui añade los campos que quieras, que en tu caso serian fNacimiento, etc

    # Si es necesario tambien modifica los campos de Django que vienen por defecto
```

De esta manera cada usuario ya vendra con dichos campos por defecto, sin necesidad de crear otro modelo y acceder a dichos datos por relaciones, etc.

Para decirle a Django que ese sera el modelo de usuario como tal, en tu `settings.py` añade la constante `AUTH_USER_MODEL`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User'
```

Despues solo has las respectivas migraciones y listo.

Para mas informacion echale un vistaso a la doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

---

Desde ahora en adelante al momento de importar el modelo `User` no debe ser de la forma convencional, debe ser asi:

```
from app_donde_esta_el_modelo.models import User
```

Otra forma mas profesional y de buena practica seria el `get_user_model()`:

> **get_user_model()** - [**Documentacion**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model)
>
> En lugar de referirse a `User` directamente, debe hacer referencia al
>   modelo de usuario utilizando `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`.
>   Este método devolverá el modelo de usuario actualmente activo: el
>   modelo de usuario personalizado si se especifica uno, o `User` de lo
>   contrario.

---

Para modificar los valores que necesites de un usuario, que es donde tienes problemas, seria de esta manera:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UsernameField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = UsernameField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # Aqui añades los campos a modificar, etc. Excepto "password" obiamente.
        fields = [...]
```

De esta manera no habra problemas con contraseñas ni nada de eso, que es donde ocurren los problemas.

Si quieres crear un formulario de registro personalisado debido a los campos añadidos, te recomiendo que el formulario para crear dicho usuario herede del form `UserCreationForm`.

Espero haberte ayudado de alguna manera.