# ¿como hacer un login en Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-urls

Algo simple solo estoy aprendiendo.-
Tengo esta clase persona con solo un nombre y contraseña

```py
class persona(models.Model):
    nombre  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

este es el url

```py
 path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
```

en la view solo tengo esto, nose que hacer mas

```py
def login(request):

    
     return render(request, 'auth/login.html')
```

y en el template

```
 <form method="POST" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" id="login"  name="nombre" placeholder="nombre">
                <input type="password" id="login"  name="password" placeholder="password">

                <input type="submit"  value="Log In">
            </form>
```

Soy nuevo en programación web :c

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo con tu modelo `persona` es de mala practica, estas creado un modelo con propositos de autenticasion, no es necesario hacerlo, ya existe el modelo `User` y un sistema de autenticasion de Django ya por defecto, echale un vistaso a esta respuesta, te puede ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320208/c%c3%b3mo-actualizar-datos-de-un-usuario-sin-que-se-modifique-la-password-en-django/321113#321113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django proporciona un sistema de `login` y de permisos, solo tienes que implementarlo:

Primero debes de verificar que en tus `INSTALLED_APPS{}` (que está en tus `settings.py`) se encuentra lo siguiente

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth',  #Para el login 
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', #para permisos  
    ....
]
```

Adicionalmente, puedes agregar a lo que tiene que redireccionar por defecto cuando se inicia sesión y cuando se cierra sesión (al final de `settings.py`) con:

```py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('index')

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('index')
```

Previamente se debe de importar `reverse_lazy`

```py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
```

Dentro de las urls.py debes de importar las views que dispone **Django** para realizar el login.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', LoginView.as_view(), name= 'login'),
    url(r'^logout$', LogoutView.as_view(), name= 'logout'),
]
```

Cabe mencionar que al ser `views` generadas por Django, estas apuntan a templates con nombres específicos, para que estás puedan funcionar en tus templates debes de crear una carpeta denominada `registration` y dentro de ella el template `login`, tal que así:

```
registration
   └───login.html
```

También puedes hacer uso de

`PasswordResetView`  =  para poder cambiar la pass

`PasswordResetDoneView` =  para decir que el cambio ya está hecho

`PasswordResetConfirmView`  =  para confirmar el cambio de la pass

`PasswordResetCompleteView`  =  para mostrar cuando el cambio ya está completo